# Sorting lucene search results

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to sort the search results of Lucene search engine from highest to lowest.

For example:

I am searching for 2 words: lucene and java

```
Searching for 'lucene'

3 results found 

ppp.txt
nnn.txt
mmm.txt


Searching for java 

5 results found 

ccc.txt
rrr.txt
qqq.txt
```

I want the order to be 5 first then 3 and display the total of the documents found.

Any Ideas would be grateful

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A `caret (^)` followed by a floating-point number will allow you to boost search terms.

For example, the query expression `lucene java^2.0` sets the `java` TermQuery to a boost of `2.0` and leaves the testing `lucene` at the default boost of `1.0`.

This would cause all the results having `java` to appear on top.